# Is there any click counter out there?

Tags: scripts

As I said, I couldn't find any program/script that does that single job, is there any software that could do that? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of clicks would you like to count? Mouse clicks? Keyboard clicks? Clicks on a  web page? You need to be much more specific.

Comment: My bad, I mean mouse clicks

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) is a mouse hook listener.

Comment: `i=0; while read; do echo $((++i)); done < <(xinput --test 12 | grep --line-buffered -F 'button press   1')` you can find your mouse id with `xinput --list`